# Laravel API delete row from db

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, delete-row, rest

While trying to delete rows by id from db as below , I am getting the error- `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`. I think no `id`  is passed to the `delete()` function in my code and am not sure how to pass it. Please help me with ur suggestions.

**Controller**

```
public function delete($id){
            
            
            $data = PersonalDetails::where('id',$id)->delete();
            // dd($data);
            if(count($data)){
    
                return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully Deleted']);
            }
            else{
                return response()->json(['message'=>'Delete Failed']);
            }
        }
```

**Route**

```
Route::group([
    'namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers',
    'middleware' => 'api',
], function ($router) {

    Route::post('delete/{id}', 'PersonalDetailsAdmin@delete');
}
```

Comment: when you `dd($data)` you should have seen that $data in an integer. same result as the method `update()`

Comment: the edit is irrelevant to your original post. accept the answer for the original question, and then open a new question for any other issue you have. it's not an open forum here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->delete()` method already returns the count of the deleted rows, so the solution would be:

```php
public function delete($id){
    
    $count = PersonalDetails::where('id',$id)->delete();
    // dd($data);
    if($count > 0 ){

        return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully Deleted']);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Delete Failed']);
    }
}
```

Comment: since `$count` is an integer, you dont even need to compare it to `0`, just `if($count) {` is enough in this case.

Comment: when i tried this, I am getting my error msg "delete failed" even if the data is getting deleted

Comment: @N69S you are correct, but this keeps the code cleaner and more readable for future reference.

Comment: @MG so the `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable` exception is resolved ?

Comment: my error resolved. Actually i was trying to delete a row that was already deleted. That's why, i got that error. But may i ask u that, passing id through url like this isn't that safe. right? What is the safest way to accomplish this?

Comment: @MG if its a public url its not that safe indeed, the url should be protected by some middleware to see if the request can be authorized or not.

If my answer helped you resolve the exception, please accept it so it may fellow programmers!

Comment: Please see the updated question.I have added middleware as such. Is my API safe now?

Comment: @MG having the id in the url is safe, as long as you verify (with midlewares & controllers) that the user has the right to this delete action. For example, use relation like this `Auth::user()->PersonalDetails()->where('id',$id)->delete();` instead of `PersonalDetails::where('id',$id)->delete();`